# Multivariate normality plots

Tags: qq-plot

To check multivariate normality, which is the best plot - a chi square qq plot for the entire set of variables or as many qqplots as the number of variables?

Comment: Which method do you think gives the most information?  (Neither is "best", though, because they give information only about marginal distributions and therefore their diagnostic capabilities are incomplete.)

Comment: Of the two which is better?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "chi square qq plot for the entire set of variables."  When I first read the question I thought it meant a QQ plot comparing the sum of squares of the values to a relevant $\chi^2$ distribution, but it now occurs to me you might have had something else in mind--I just don't know exactly what.

Comment: chi square qq plot = squared Mahalanobis distance against the Chi square quantile. I obtained it by giving qq plot = true when Mardia's MVN test was used in R.

Answer (score 1):

There are some test like the Mardia’s Multivariate Normality Test, Royston’s Multivariate Normality Test but i think chi q-q plot is ideal for showing multivariate normality . Here is vignette in R which you might be interested in 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MVN/vignettes/MVN.pdf